# Unresponsive input

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to make a game where you type in commands and the game responds.

Question: Why is my user input not responding or just kind of breaking out of the program when I enter something?

Here is the part

```
   # paths
    def path1():
        coins = 0
        gem = 0
        print("Welcome to, community manager.")
        print("Type start")
        if cmd == "start":
            print(f'''Welcome {user} I will give you 10 coins to start with.
            you can always type balance to check your coins
            ''')
            sleep(1.5)
            coins = coins + 10
```

There is also a while loop running the cmd = input(">>> ") but it is at line one.

Comment: A [mre] needs to contain enough code to cause the problem when run without changes **as part of the question itself**. A GitHub link is fine as long as it's strictly supplemental -- people need to be able to answer the question, or learn from its answers, using only information contained in the text of the question itself.

Comment: you never re-prompt for input after the "Type start" so cmd is actually still `""job hut"` at the time that this code is run. You don't give them a chance to type "start"!

Comment: Does "Welcome to community manager" print? If so, add `print("cmd", cmd)` to see what the command is. Generally, sprinkle prints through your code so you can see what is executing.

Comment: @Esther I do not get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in your code where you ask for `input`. After your `print` statement where you say "Type start" just add:

```py
cmd = input('>')
```